# What is the difference between these 2 twisted pairs?

Tags: networking, switch, cable, gigabit-ethernet

I have two cables marked:

1. BELDEN 1583e utp cat5e 4pr awg24 iso/iec 11801 en50173 ec verified 
   100 ohm 1002069
2. ESSENTIAL utp cat5e by nexans EC verified 4pr awg24
   lu0306

Both connected to TL-SG108E http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-SG108E#spec
I can establish 1 Gb connection with second ESSENTIAL cable, but not with the first one. To me both look the same. What might be the problem? Both cables are ended same way 100BASE-T568B.

I don't think pins are the issue. I have separate piece of BELDEN cable not working at Gb speed.

Comment: You're sure the terminations are correct??

Comment: Double checked, I am sure terminations are correct.

Comment: Migrate to network engineering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most logical explanation would be that there's 1 pin interrupted (4,5,7 or 8). that would cause the cable to work in 100Mb-mode but not in gigabit mode.
Check into thins before anything else.

Comment: I've checked both wires with cable tester. Every pin looks fine. Is there another way to test it?

Comment: You have to watch out on cable testers, the cheap ones will tell you that all 4 pairs are hooked up correctly, but will not detect if one of the pairs is in the proper position but with the pair reversed on one end (solid/striped connected backwards).

Comment: Against all odds I decided to redo both terminations. And Bingo. It worked despite the good readings from cable tester and proper order of twisted pair. It might have something to do with poor material of the connectors. Had to replace terminations in 5/7 cables. Thank you for help.

Comment: Your welcomed. Improper contact is common for some type of connectors.